# Problema enviando apikey en los header http de angular 4

Tags: angular

Tengo una Api REST que requiere el apikey en los headers para validar, estoy haciendo la consulta con angular 4, pero no se envia el apikey en los headers.

Si hago la consulta con PostMan funciona sin problema. Estoy atorado en este punto, agradezco su ayuda amigos.

Necesito que se envíe el "apikey" en los headers de la petición algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del componente.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private apiURL = 'http://192.168.1.53/joinn-api/v1'
  data: any = {}

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){
    this.getData()
    this.getEvents()

  }

  getData(){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
    return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/event/?token=cf6fb41f1d21834d34c8a8c8b3827181', {headers: headers})
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  getEvents(){
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })

  }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Envía tu **header apiKey** seteándolo con el [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor) de Angular +4, así no tendrás que repetirlo en cada petición que hagas contra tu API.

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46172188/6628564)

Answer (score 0):

Si el Backend lo que espera recibir es el apikey en las cabeceras (headers) Y no como parámetro en la URL(query) has lo siguiente:

```
getData(){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('apikey', 'cf6fb41f1d21834d34c8a8c8b3827181');
  return this.http.get(this.apiURL + '/event', { headers: headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json'))
  .map(response => response.json());
}


getEvents(){
  this.getData().subscribe(
    event => console.log(event),
    error => console.error('Error: ' + error),
    () => console.log('Completedo!')
  );
}
```

Espero y te sirva y solucione tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo hice tal cual sugeriste pero la petición la hace como "OPTION" y validando el motor de red no manda el "apikey"